# Tensorflow dense model keeps spitting the same output

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to have a model output a probability when given 13 variables. My training set is composed of:

`train_x` which is an array with shape `(303, 13)`

```
array([[61.,  1.,  0., ...,  2.,  1.,  3.],
   [58.,  0.,  3., ...,  2.,  0.,  2.],
   [51.,  1.,  3., ...,  2.,  1.,  2.],
   ...,
   [66.,  0.,  3., ...,  0.,  0.,  2.],
   [34.,  0.,  1., ...,  2.,  0.,  2.],
   [42.,  1.,  3., ...,  2.,  2.,  2.]])
```

and `train_y` which is an array with shape `(303,)`

```
array([0, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1])
```

This is the model I am trying to train:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(13),
    keras.layers.Dense(6, activation='sigmoid'),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax')
])

loss = keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam()

model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=opt, metrics=[keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()])
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('model_weights.hdf5', monitor='loss', verbose=1,            
save_best_only=True, mode='min')
chkpt_callback = [checkpoint]
```

And the problem is that after training, the model keeps giving the same output of `[1.]` when I ran it on both training and test sets:

Here is the output it performed on the test set with shape `(13, 13)`

```
tf.Tensor(
[[1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]], shape=(13, 1), dtype=float32)
```

It could also be helpful to note that the model's accuracy during training stays constant and the loss only decreases a bit:

```
Epoch 1/30
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.8467 - binary_accuracy: 0.5345

Epoch 00001: loss improved from inf to 0.84666, saving model to heart_weights.hdf5
Epoch 2/30
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.7523 - binary_accuracy: 0.5345

Epoch 00002: loss improved from 0.84666 to 0.75233, saving model to heart_weights.hdf5
Epoch 3/30
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.7207 - binary_accuracy: 0.5345

Epoch 00003: loss improved from 0.75233 to 0.72074, saving model to heart_weights.hdf5
Epoch 4/30
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.7163 - binary_accuracy: 0.5345

Epoch 00004: loss improved from 0.72074 to 0.71626, saving model to heart_weights.hdf5
Epoch 5/30
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.7127 - binary_accuracy: 0.5345

Epoch 00005: loss improved from 0.71626 to 0.71273, saving model to heart_weights.hdf5
Epoch 6/30
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.7087 - binary_accuracy: 0.5345
```

I've tried different optimizers and learning rates, but the issue stays the same. I'm not sure how to address this.

Comment: Perhaps your model isn't dense enough to learn the featurs. Also do some input regularisation so that the model inputs dont blow up.

Comment: I suggest reading up on what `softmax` activation function does and what it's for. Its output always sums up to 1. Since your output is a single number, that's what you get, 1.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `softmax` as activation function in a layer with 1 neuron. If you know the [softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) function creates a probability distribution over outputs, which the sum of them is 1. So, if you have 1 output, you will always get 1 as the output.

If you are classifying binary, you may use `sigmoid` as activation function for your last layer instead of `softmax`.